# ZF2 Mail - HTML sent as attachment

Tags: email, zend-framework2

I'm face of a strange error :
I use Zend\Mail\Message and Zend\Mime\Message to send emails in HTML format with or without attachements.
Everything was worked fine but now the HTML is sent as an attchement.

I'll put some code (I've created a class to send my emails) :

```
<?php
class EmailManager
{   
    static protected $_instance;

    protected $sender      = null;
    protected $message     = null;
    protected $mimeMessage = null;
    protected $parts       = null;
    protected $subject     = null;

    .....

    protected function __construct() {
        self::init();           
    }

    protected function init()
    {
        $this->sender = new Sendmail();
        $this->message = new Message();
        $this->mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
        $this->parts = array();
        $this->subject = DEFAULT_SUBJECT;
    } 

    protected function loadReset(...)
    {
            ...

        $subject = '...';
        $content = '
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    SOM HTML CONTENT
                </body>
            </html>
        ';

        $body = new Part($content);
        $body->type    = 'text/html';
        $body->charset = 'UTF-8';
        $body->disposition = \Zend\Mime\Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;

        $this->parts[] = $body;
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function sendTo($receiver)
    {   
        $this->mimeMessage->setParts($this->parts);

        $this->message->setEncoding(self::ENCODING)
                      ->addFrom(self::FROM_ADRESS, self::FROM_NAME)
                      ->addTo($receiver)
                      ->setSubject($this->subject)
                      ->setBody($this->mimeMessage);

        $this->sender->send($this->message);
    }
    ....
    } 
?>
```

Then I call this class like this :

```
$emailMng = EmailManager::getInstance();
$emailMng->load('reset', /* some params */ ));
$emailMng->sendTo($user->get('email'));
```

This is really strange cause this happens even if use `$body->disposition = \Zend\Mime\Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: [send email with attached files in ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066078/send-email-with-attached-files-in-zf2#answer-17486871)
But withouth the pdf attachment, if you combine the message and make a new part with multipart/alternative it works.

It's not a really nice interface for such a common task ;)