# PHP mail() function ... empty message sent

Tags: php, html, email, attachment

I try to send an email from my server to recipient, no problem, the email is sent.
I have TEXT HTML in this email, and a PDF attachment...

The problem is: I receive the mail, I receive the PDF, but there is NO text!

Here is my code if you can help :)

```
$filepath = '../../path/file.pdf';
if (!preg_match("#^[a-z0-9._-]+@(hotmail|live|msn).[a-z]{2,4}$#", $email))
{
    $br = "\r\n";
}
else
{
    $br = "\n";
}
$message_html= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"".$br;
$message_html.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$br;
$message_html.= '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
      <title>mytitle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
      my content!
      </div

    </body>
</html>';

$boundary = "-----=".md5(rand());
$boundary_alt = "-----=".md5(rand());

$subject = "mysubject";

$attached_file = file_get_contents($filepath);
$attached_file = chunk_split(base64_encode($attached_file));
$pos=strrpos($filepath,"/");
if($pos!==false)$file_name=substr($filepath,$pos+1);
else $file_name=$filepath;
$pos=strrpos($filepath,".");
if($pos!==false)$file_type="/".substr($filepath,$pos+1);
else $file_type="";

$attached = "\n\n". "--" .$boundary . "\nContent-Type: application".$file_type."; name=\"$file_name\"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"tickets.pdf\"\r\n\n".$attached_file . "--" . $boundary . "--";

//=====HEADER
$header = "To: ".$email." ".$br;
$header.= "From: frrrrrom".$br;
$header.= "Cc: cccccccc".$br;
$header.= "Reply-to: qdfqsf".$br;
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$br;
$header.= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;".$br." boundary=\"$boundary\"".$br;
//==========

$body = $message_html.$attached;

mail($email,$subject,$body,$header);
```

Comment: There are many subtleties to sending email. Instead of constructing everything yourself I recommend using a free library, for example Zend Framework 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066078/send-email-with-attached-files-in-zf2

Comment: thx for the reply but... well... even if it's not perfect... i'd like to do it myself... ^^ maybe it's boundary causing issue... anyone has an idea?

Comment: Check whether you can receive plain text. And in $message_html variable use single quotes (') instead of double quotes (") and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would if I had to debug it, is to remove the attached PDF and check if it sends the text and then try to add it back.

Also you can try printing to your screen with var_dump the $body and the others vars and share it with us and then it'll be easier to spot the problem. As probably it's with what you send which doesn't match the format of email sending.

Comment: This is THE idea! :D i tried, and found that if i DONT attach the PDF file, the mail content (html) IS visible... BUT if i attach the PDF, there is no text displayed... where does this trick come from? how to solve this issue? is it a "content-type" mistake i did?

Comment: The problem was a missing "--".$boundary before the text... code wasnt clear enough to delimitate html or attachment... so it was one or another, not both! THANKS ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that when you are sending an email in php, the text has to be set inline. Also you didn't have your closing div finished (you had `</div`), this may have caused you not to be able to see the text, but it was there.

```
$message_html.= '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>mytitle</title></head><body>';
$message_html.= '<div>my content!</div>'; // The unfinished div
$message_html.= '</body></html>';
```

Comment: It's unlikely that a single missing `>` would cause nothing to be displayed, browsers are pretty good at fixing bad HTML http://jsfiddle.net/n4YVU/

Comment: @JuanMendes if you have ever messed with automated html emails, you would know that html in emails is very different than in page html. It has a mind of its own.

Comment: I must admit, I don't have a lot of experience with HTML emails

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is not an unclosed <div> problem... even with the good bracket, the mail is empty... but something interesting found, check the comment i'll leave to previous answer ;)